# Sort list of numbers using the zsh shell in Mac OS X

Tags: terminal, zsh, sort

Using Mac OS X zsh shell, how can I ascending sort the following list of numbers? I have tried the command line `sort` (without any options) but the output is not accurate.

The below list of numbers is the output from the following command line: `dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Side Note: Pay attention to a couple of numbers from the list such as *-2*, *0*, etc.

```
83
263
273
55
260
87
79
33
67
235
245
97
229
93
258
32
82
262
202
236
280
259
212
72
77
257
275
59
220
271
244
241
214
227
215
270
71
254
265
98
278
247
56
261
240
25
274
96
84
218
219
279
234
232
231
233
230
246
217
239
211
205
272
26
78
248
54
65
253
74
268
222
228
24
242
243
441
249
27
216
76
269
277
60
203
31
92
200
89
75
73
13
94
266
210
91
282
208
99
95
213
4
224
221
88
70
252
251
1
501
-2
0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the *manual page* for the `sort` *command*:

```
 -n, --numeric-sort, --sort=numeric
         Sort fields numerically by arithmetic value.  Fields are supposed
         to have optional blanks in the beginning, an optional minus sign,
         zero or more digits (including decimal point and possible thou-
         sand separators).
```

<sup>Note: For a descending order sort, add the `-r` *option*, e.g. : `| sort -nr`</sup>

Adding `| sort -n` to your *command*, and using the *output* in your question, will *output* e.g.:

```
-2
0
1
4
13
24
25
26
27
31
32
33
54
55
56
59
60
65
67
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
82
83
84
87
88
89
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
200
202
203
205
208
210
211
212
213
214
215
216
217
218
219
220
221
222
224
227
228
229
230
231
232
233
234
235
236
239
240
241
242
243
244
245
246
247
248
249
251
252
253
254
257
258
259
260
261
262
263
265
266
268
269
270
271
272
273
274
275
277
278
279
280
282
441
501
```

If you are new to using shell commands or the command line, many of them have helpful manuals (and some manuals are also spectacularly unhelpful) or built in help.

```
man sort
sort --help
```